# Comparing two columns in two files using awk with duplicates

Tags: awk

File 1

```
A4gnt   0   0   0   0.3343
Aaas    2.79    2.54    1.098   0.1456
Aacs    0.94    0.88    1.063   0.6997
Aadac   0   0   0   0.3343
Aadacl2 0   0   0   0.3343
Aadat   0.01    0   1.723   0.7222
Aadat   0.06    0.03    1.585   0.2233
Aaed1   0.28    0.24    1.14    0.5337
Aaed1   1.24    1.27    0.976   0.9271
Aaed1   15.91   13.54   1.175   0.163
Aagab   1.46    1.14    1.285   0.3751
Aagab   6.12    6.3 0.972   0.6569
Aak1    0.02    0.01    1.716   0.528
Aak1    0.1 0.19    0.561   0.159
Aak1    0.14    0.19    0.756   0.5297
Aak1    0.16    0.18    0.907   0.6726
Aak1    0.21    0   0   0.066
Aak1    0.26    0.27    0.967   0.9657
Aak1    0.54    1.65    0.325   0.001
Aamdc   0.04    0   15.461  0.0875
Aamdc   1.03    1.01    1.019   0.8817
Aamdc   1.27    1.26    1.01    0.9285
Aamdc   7.21    6.94    1.039   0.7611
Aamp    0.06    0.05    1.056   0.9136
Aamp    0.11    0.11    1.044   0.9227
Aamp    0.12    0.13    0.875   0.7584
Aamp    0.22    0.2 1.072   0.7609
```

File 2

```
Adar
Ak3
Alox15b
Ampd2
Ampd3
Ankrd17
Apaf1
Aplp1
Arih1
Atg14
Aurkb
Bcl2l14
Bmp2
Brms1l
Cactin
Camta2
Cav1
Ccr5
Chfr
Clock
Cnot1
Crebrf
Crtc3
Csnk2b
Cul3
Cx3cl1
Dnaja3
Dnmt1
Dtl
Ednra
Eef1e1
Esr1
Ezr
Fam162a
Fas
Fbxo30
Fgr
Flcn
Foxp3
Frzb
Fzd6
Gdf3
Hey2
Hnf4
```

The desired output would be wherever matches in the first column from both file print out all the columns in the first file (including duplicates).

I've tried

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5; next} { if($1 in a) { print $0,a[$1] } }' File2 File1 > output
```

But for some reason I'm getting just few hits. Does anyone know why?

Comment: There's no common for 1st column in both files, all column1 in File1 starts with A, and you can see there's no shared keyword in File2

Comment: Maybe you should show what you get vs what you expect (which is an important part of creating an MCVE — [MCVE])? Another part would be cutting out the entries in file 2 that don't start with 'A' since the data in file 1 only contains lines starting with 'A'. While reading file 1, you zap any duplicate records, keeping only the last for a given value in column 1.  That may be most of your trouble, but it is hard to be sure.

Comment: Thanks guys for answering me. I'm sorry but this was just an example, my list is huge and I have several that matches but is not been printing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read second file first, and store 1st column values in array `arr` as array keys, and then read first file, if 1st column of file1 exists in array `arr` which was created using file2, then print current row/record from file1.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1];next}$1 in arr' file2 file1
```

***Advantage:***

if you use `a[$1]=$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5; next`, if there's any data with same key will be replaced with previous value,

but if you use `arr[$1];next`, we store just unique key, and `$1 in arr` takes care of duplicate record even if it exists

Comment: check the source, no shared keywords, OP's command works properly

Comment: This is still valid advice; it will deal with the 'repeated occurrences of key' — once there are also some common key values.

Comment: @haifzhan, true, why to use so much resource in storing 4 column in array, better read it in other way, save resource, also OP tried other way where there is chance of loosing if there's any duplicate

Comment: @AkshayHegde I agree, but the question is `But for some reason I'm getting just few hits. Does anyone know why? 

`

Comment: @haifzhan, its really depends on how you read OP said `
The desired output would be wherever matches in the first column from both file print out all the columns in the first file (including duplicates)`

Comment: The OPs code already does exactly what you're suggesting, it's just got a bunch of extraneous code around it.

Comment: Thanks @AkshayHegde that was helpful. But I still cannot get all common genes. For example the Adar gene from file 2 does show up in file 1 but is not printing out.